# Generalizing a C++ pattern

Tags: c++, linux, templates, gcc, c++11

I'm programming in a very static environment and would like to generalize the problem/code in the best way possible, to make it clean and avoid any boilerplate code. This is my case; I'm developing a modification system which sits between the *program* and the *extensions*, where the extensions will be forwarded the API calls. When my modification gets loaded by the program, I receive a pointer to a table consisting entirely of function pointers.

```
struct APITable
{
 void (*MouseClick)(int, int);
 void (*MouseLeave)(bool);
 int (*MouseRet)(float, int);
 // And about a 200 more
 // ......
};
```

In this function I set the callback functions/pointers, to point at my own (i.e `apiTable->MouseClick = &MyMouseClick;`). I'm trying to extend this framework (since it only allows one modification at a time) to support multiple plugins. This is done by loading additional plugins (as libraries) and then forward all callbacks (such as `MouseClick`) to the loaded plugins. This is an example;

```
void MyMouseClick(int x, int y)
{
 bool blockOriginal = false;

 // Iterate over all plugins
 if(plugin_function_is_defined_pre)
  blockOriginal = call_plugin_callback_pre(x, y);

 if(!blockOriginal)
  EngineMouseClick(x, y); // This is the programs "engine" function, which I have to call if I want normal execution flow

 // Iterate over all plugins
 if(plugin_function_is_defined_post)
  call_plugin_callback_post(x, y);
}
```

This is a very simplified procedure but I think it tells everything that needs to be told. Since I have over 200 functions there's no way I would copy and paste all this boilerplate code. The normal procedure would probably be a `#define`, one for `void` functions and one for functions with a return value. Although this works, I would definately prefer another solution (which might not be possible since C++ is a statically typed language).

The point is; I want to generalize this procedure in a clean and efficient way avoiding any boilerplate code. Worth mentioning is that the functions may *override* the original functions return value, in callbacks not declared as void.

So to strip it to the bones: `Program->MyExtension->Plugins&Engine`

NOTE: I do *not* want to use any language but C++, and will use C++11 features if necessary!

EDIT: In case of interest, this is how my modification gets loaded by the program:

```
extern "C" ModLoad(APITable * apiTable)
{
 apiTable->MouseClick = &MyMouseClick;
 apiTable->MouseLeave = &MyMouseLeave;
 // And so on
 // ...
}
```

Comment: "a pointer to a table consisting entirely of function pointers" - it sounds a little like you're trying to reimplement C++ in C++...

Comment: Also, it's not clear how your 1st code snippet relates to your 2nd code snippet.

Comment: @Oli - something like Spring or other IoC framework in C++ maybe

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I hope I've explained it enough now. See my 'edit'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> which might not be possible since C++ is a statically typed language

If only C++ had a statically-typed way to write generic code that can be customised for different parameters, maybe some kind of template facility?  ;-)

N.B. I have no idea how you intend to handle return values or what `blockOriginal` or the callbacks are meant to do, so this is just a sketch.

```
template<typename Res, typename... Args>
  Res call_plugin_func(Enum funcID, Res (*origFunc)(Args...), Args... args)
  {
    Res res = Res();
    bool blockOriginal = false;

    // Iterate over all plugins, looking for defs of funcID
    if(plugin_function_is_defined_pre)
      blockOriginal = call_plugin_callback_pre(args...);

    if(!blockOriginal)
      res = origFunc(args...);

    // Iterate over all plugins
    if(plugin_function_is_defined_post)
      call_plugin_callback_post(args...);

    return res;
  }

template<typename... Args>
  void call_plugin_func(Enum funcID, void (*origFunc)(Args...), Args... args)
  {
    bool blockOriginal = false;

    // Iterate over all plugins, looking for defs of funcID
    if(plugin_function_is_defined_pre)
      blockOriginal = call_plugin_callback_pre(args...);

    if(!blockOriginal)
      origFunc(args...);

    // Iterate over all plugins
    if(plugin_function_is_defined_post)
      call_plugin_callback_post(args...);
  }

void MyMouseClick(int x, int y)
{
  call_plugin_func(ID_MyMouseClick, &EngineMouseClick, x, y);
}
```

(Two function templates are needed because the one returning void has a different body, it can't declare `res` to be type `void`.)

Comment: For a void function is perfectly valid to return an expression of type `void`, as it is the case for another function returning void.

Comment: Yes, but the OP said "Worth mentioning is that the functions may override the original functions return value, in callbacks not declared as void." so maybe the function template body needs to do `Res value = plugin(args...); ... return Res;` but that would be impossible when Res is void, so you might need a different function template. Edited to reflect that.

Comment: In C++11, `Res res = Res();` is written `Res res{};`.

Comment: This was a very interesting post! I take it variadic templates are a C++11 limited feature? I'll definitely see if I can come up with a fitting solution like this one. And yes, as mentioned earlier my version was simplified, and I will use `Res value = plugin(args...);`

Comment: @ildjarn, good point. Upvoted but I haven't edited it because some compilers support variadic templates as an extension to C++03, but don't support initializer lists in C++03 mode.

Comment: The question is tagged `c++11`, not `c++03-emulating-some-c++11`. ;-]

Comment: @ildjarn Haha yes, it's no problem at all. I just have not gained any experience with C++11 yet, so I thought I should ask :)

Comment: @ildjarn: Correction: In C++11, `Res res=Res();` generally can be written as `Res res{};` — first, the old syntax is still valid (making "is written as" wrong), and second, it is completely possible (although very bad style) to write classes where both have completely different semantics.

Comment: @celtschk : Is idiomatically written as, then, if you want to be picky. ;-]

Comment: @ildjarn: Can you give any sources for your claim that it is *idiomatically* written that way (as opposed to just: certain people consider that way better)?

Comment: It's idiomatic among people who know C++11 properly ;)  The new syntax was invented _specifically_ to replace other forms of initialization as a single, consistent syntax.  My version requires an accessible copy constructor, but ildjarn's doesn't, so it is **better** because it's more flexible and doesn't rely on copy elision to be optimally efficient